# What is the GCP_USERNAME when replicating from MySQL to Google Cloud SQL

Tags: mysql, gcloud, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to configure permissions on my external server so that Google Cloud SQL can replicate. I've been following [the documentation here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/custom-import-replication-from-external#update-replica-user). I cannot figure out what value to use for `GCP_USERNAME`.

```
UPDATE mysql.user
SET Host='NEW_HOST' WHERE Host='OLD_HOST' AND User='USERNAME';
GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE, EXECUTE ON *.*
TO 'GCP_USERNAME'@'HOST';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Is it the service account for the Cloud SQL instance? Is it a MySQL user? I can't find any more details in docs. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Posted an answer, is it helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [document](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/custom-import-replication-from-external#example),

`GCP_USERNAME: The username for the GCP user account.`

If you check the example in the [document](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/custom-import-replication-from-external#example), it is clearly stated that

```
UPDATE mysql.user
SET Host='192.0.2.0' WHERE Host='%' AND User='replicationUser';
GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE, EXECUTE ON *.*
TO 'gcp_user'@'gmail.com';  // line 3
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

As you can see in the above example, Line 3 uses `@gmail.com` domain. So it is clear that `GCP_USERNAME` is MYSQL user’s account

So, for

> Is it the service account for the Cloud SQL instance? Is it a MySQL user?

For service accounts the format will be like `service-account-name@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com` where `gserviceaccount` is domain for service accounts.   for more details you can refer to [Types of service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#types) document.

So GCP_USERNAME  refers to MySQL user account